# Data is updated in the database but with error

Tags: php

In my system, I have a function to update the data. After I click 'update' button, the data is updated at the database, but it also displays an error like this:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: badgeid in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker\pages\manage_engineer_admin\edit_engineer_admin.php
>   on line 33
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: fullname in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker\pages\manage_engineer_admin\edit_engineer_admin.php
>   on line 210
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: roles_id in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker\pages\manage_engineer_admin\edit_engineer_admin.php
>   on line 220
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: roles_id in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker\pages\manage_engineer_admin\edit_engineer_admin.php
>   on line 221
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: team_id in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker\pages\manage_engineer_admin\edit_engineer_admin.php
>   on line 231
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: team_id in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker\pages\manage_engineer_admin\edit_engineer_admin.php
>   on line 231

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "";
require_once "../../config/configPDO.php";
require_once "../../config/check.php";

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   
  $badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];

  // checking empty fields
  if(empty($badgeid)) { 

    if(empty($badgeid)) {
      echo "<font color='red'>Fac_Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

  } else {  
    //updating the badgeid
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET roles_id = :roles_id, team_id = :team_id WHERE badgeid = :badgeid";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $query->bindParam(':roles_id', $_POST['roles_id']);
    $query->bindParam(':team_id', $_POST['team_id']);
    $query->bindParam(':badgeid', $_POST['badgeid']);
    $query->execute();

    //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
    header("Location: ../dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
  }
}

//getting id from url
$badgeid = $_GET['badgeid']; //line 33

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN roles on users.roles_id = roles.roles_id WHERE badgeid = :badgeid";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':badgeid' => $badgeid));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $badgeid = $row["badgeid"];;
  $fullname = $row["fullname"];
  $roles_id = $row["roles_id"];
  $team_id = $row['team_id'];
  $roles_name = $row["roles_name"];
}

$smt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM team");
$smt->execute();
$data = $smt->fetchAll();

?>

   <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
  <table class = "table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><b>Full Name</b></td>
      <td width="80%"><?php echo $fullname; ?></td> //line 210
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><b>Badge ID</b></td>
      <td width="80%"><?php echo $badgeid; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><b>Role</b></td>
      <td width="80%">
        <select class="form-control" name="roles_id">
          <option value="1" <?php echo $roles_id == '1'? 'selected': '';?> >Super Admin</option> //line 220
          <option value="2" <?php echo $roles_id == '2'? 'selected': '';?> >Engineer</option> //line 221
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="badgeid" value="<?php echo $badgeid ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><b>Team</b></td>
      <td width="80%">
      <select class="form-control" name="team_id">
      <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["team_id"]; ?>" <?php echo $row["team_id"] == $team_id ? 'selected': ''; ?>><?php echo $row["team_name"]; ?></option> //line 231
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="badgeid" value="<?php echo $badgeid ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>  
  </table><br>
  <div align="center">
    <td><button class ="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="update" value="Update" onclick="update()">Update</button></td>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: dump $rows  array to see if contains data or no

Comment: @Hamza how to do it? At line where?

Comment: before foreach loop print_r($rows)

Comment: @Hamza like this? var_dump($rows)

Comment: yes  var_dump($rows);

Comment: @Hamza has data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203887/discussion-between-radamel-falcao-and-hamza).

Comment: You are using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` for the form action. This will not pass the `badgeid` as a `$_GET` variable. If you want to keep the GET variables you should be using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` as the form action.

This removes the `$_GET` variables from the redirected page which means that you will be redirected to eg `index.php` instead of `index.php?badgeid=1`

This as a result makes this line throw a notice `$badgeid = $_GET['badgeid'];`
and makes your query to have no results so the rest variables are never initialized which in turn results to the rest notices you get.

In order to solve this you could be using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead which will keep the variables or save and pass the `badgeid` by other means.

Comment: Can you see my another problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259039/json-error-cannot-login-the-android-apps